# Quantify the equity of position (button) heads up

Tags: probability

Can the value of the button be quantified heads up.

Is there an optimal number of hands to play assuming the SB is going to play GTO?

Or if there is an EV based solution?

Can use fixed sized bets if necessary.  Can assume every hand go to showdown.

Same for SB how many hands should call / raise.

Comment: I tried but I had to make so many assumptions that it would not represent live play.

Comment: I agree with your comment here. I think there are too many assumptions that have to be made here that it'd be pretty hard, unless you're an incredible maths wizard, to have a quantified method of calculating this. As you said it would only really represent control situations with many of the factors accounted for.

Comment: Not good enough for an answer but if you play 1/2 the hands and win 1/2 of those and get one extra 8 bb bet then 2bb.  And you get away from a call in some spots for a value of like 1bb.

Comment: Under WHAT strategy / Having WHAT stacks? You talked at least once regarding harrington zones. If you want to talk about someone playing GTO, I think you should state ALL the restrictions and variables in your model.

I'd prefer an EV-based solution (given an API -currently existing- to compare hands in the river ... I think one could implement a similar one).

Answer (score -1):

If you assume every hand goes to showdown, you can easily calculate the value of the button:

0 or 1, depending on your notation.